# Static Table Cell in Dynamic Table View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm using Core Data to save my dynamic UITableView (not controller, AFAIK you can't have a static table view in a UITableView). I was wondering if it was possible to add a separate section to my table view with just one static cell inside? I tried looking but I couldn't find anything so far! I just need a point in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Scott says, you have to stay with a dynamic table view.

However, you **can** have multiple `UITableViewCell`'s (with different reuse identifiers) in your table, so just create two different cells and return the appropriate one, based on the indexPath provided in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way that a cell can only be created on the first startup? I don't want it to create the cell everytime the view is loaded or something. Thanks.

Comment: It will remain in memory until the view is unloaded as long as you are reusing cells.  It is cheap to create one cell though, so unless you are doing something really odd I wouldn't worry about creating it when the view loads.

Comment: You could always create the cell in the app delegate though if you really need to create it at startup.  Normally creating it on demand is better though.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of putting it in the App Delegate, but wouldn't that mean that every time someone launches the app, the same cell would be created? (wouldn't there be hundreds of duplicate cells (if the use launched the app hundreds of times?))?

Comment: No, you do `if (!cell) { // Create the cell }` so that it only does it once.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a table is either completely static or completely dynamic. If part of your table view needs to be dynamic, you'll have to make the whole table view dynamic and implement the delegate methods for the static cells as well.

Comment: Ay...That's a disappointment, guess I'll just have to add an image trying to represent a section of the table view, and when it's highlighted, ill make the cell blue, trying to make it as realistic as possible :P Thanks for the answer!